# unable to start a docker container running ember.js image, node_modules empty

Tags: docker, ember.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to get ember.js to run in a docker container based on the image [danlynn/ember-cli](https://store.docker.com/community/images/danlynn/ember-cli) image

Tried different versions of Dockerfile and docker compose.yml, but I always end up with the docker-compose up command complaining of the following :

> node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`

The image and container are created, but the container will not start.

I am new to the docker world, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am guessing I need to run npm install for the error to go away, but I added it to the Dockerfile so that It would run as the image is built, but that did not seem to help.

Here is my Dockerfile contents:

```
FROM danlynn/ember-cli
WORKDIR /code
COPY package.json /code
COPY bower.json /code
RUN ember init
RUN ember init --yarn
RUN bower --allow-root install
RUN npm install
COPY . /code
CMD ["ember", "serve"]
```

and the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  ember_gui:
    build: .
    container_name: ember_dev
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
       - "4200:4200"
       - "7020:7020"
       - "5779:5779"
```

Finally, here is the package.json just in case

```
{
  "name": "EmberUI",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Test app GUI",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Testing",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after much experimentation, I was able to get an ember instance running in docker based on the danlynn/ember-cli image

Lessons learned:

1.- The image is apparently setup to run in the "myApp" directory in the container. I was trying to define a "code" directory to put all the files, but apparently it really did not like that.

2.- The image needs to be initialized after it is installed by running ember init on the service. Not sure why putting the command in a Dockerfile did not work, but you just have to run the following command before you bring the container up with docker-compose up:

```
docker-compose run --rm ember_gui ember init
```

where ember_gui is the name of the ember service as per the docker-compose.yml file.

3.- The ember initialization will create a lot of files and sub-directories, so make sure to run it in a directory that has nothing else in it for clarity.

Anyways, here is the content of my docker-compose.yml in case it is useful to anyone else (note that I am no longer using a separate Dockerfile and instead using the image directly):

```
version: "3"

services:
  ember_gui:
    image: danlynn/ember-cli
    container_name: ember_dev
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    command: ember server
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
      - "7020:7020"
      - "7357:7357"
```

To run it the first time:

```
docker-compose run --rm ember_gui ember init
docker-compose up
```

After that, you can just run

```
docker-compose up
```

Comment: Thanks for writing up your solution :)